# Setting Env Python Path at run time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my code in the below structure

**Folder Libs:** 
*init*.py

```py
import lib1
import lib2
import lib3
```

- folder lib1
- folder lib2
- folder lib3

**Folder Tests**

- Test.py

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../Libs'))

import lib1
```

I get the error lib1 not found, any idea what could be wrong? the `sys.path.append` should have included the folder Libs to the path and so the library lib1, lib2 & lib3 should have ideally be included. Not sure why its not recognized. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following knowing that `ClassNameLib1` and `ClassNameLib2` are the names of the classes in the `lib1_file` and `lib2_file` files containing those classes placed in the `lib1` and `lib2` folders :

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from libs.lib1.lib1_file import ClassNameLib1
from libs.lib2.lib2_file import ClassNameLib2
```

However, we can also add some informations in the `__init__.py` in the folder `libs` using the `__all__` variable :

```py
__all__ = [
    'lib1',
    'lib2',
    'lib3'
]
```

And in the folder `lib1` we can add also an `__init__.py` file containing for all folders and files :

```py
from .lib1_file import ClassNameLib1

__all__ = [
    'ClassNameLib1'
]
```

Doing that, it allows you to only call `import libs` to get everything you need in your project.

Comment: This does work, but there are too many packages in Libs, I didnt want to load them individually. Is there a way to load all the packages? I thought __init__ under any folder should be able to import packages under its subfolder, but does not seem to be doing that.

Comment: Hi @RajeshS, I updated the answer to allow you to call just `import libs` in your project. Do you think it answers your problem or does it still implies too much files to do that ?

Comment: When we have the path setup in the env variable, it works without needing to explicitly state the higher level folders, any idea why we have to implicitly include the path when we have appended the path to syspath?